# What is the best way to speed up and run a website heavy on video content - CDN?

Tags: vb.net, cdn, vod

I have developed a website which allows users to upload videos which can be watched by other users. It all works fine apart from videos with a bigger resolution, will sometimes freeze. What is the best way to go about this? I am working on a function to resize the videos to 720p or less. I am also looking at CDN's. The website is written in asp.net/vb.net and uses a simple html5 video tag to play videos. I am experimenting with a CDN at the moment and I have changed my video path from https://www.example.com/videos to the nee cdn path.. https://example-13fc.example.com/videos but still my videos appear to freeze. Is there something more I need to do? Is there a company which can assist better with this than a simple cdn provider? Any help appreciated.

Comment: akamai media steraming, is one option which have been used succesfuly in a company I was working to stream musinc and videos to users. Other CDNs / services are possible

Comment: mostly opinion-based question though

Comment: Have you considered the problem may not be your website but the hardware?  Could be anything from client side, network or server causing the freeze.  and what does freeze mean?  Is the client as a whole that stops responding, is it just the video that pauses.  Does it start responding again after a delay?  You've really given us no information to assist you.  This is not the right place to be asking for software recomendations

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should do is look at the bitrate of the videos you are offering.  If the bitrate is >> than the network connection - the video will stall.  Since you cannot control your customer's network connections - it is best to make the videos as small as possible.

ffprobe is built into FFMPEG and will give you that value.  I have a web based version of FFprobe:

https://www.streamclarity.com/probe?url=
and it can report the bitrate of your video.

To make your videos smaller -obvioulsy smaller dimensions help - you can also look at lowering quality.
Another great way to improve playback is video streaming: faster connections get high quality streams... slower connections get lower quality (but they play!).  That way those with fast connections and big screens can still get HD or 4K videos.

Comment: bitrate problem over slow connections can be solved with caching video up to given minutes befiore start playing. Thedn while the previous part plays fetch the next part and so on..